# Make foreign key as primary key in xml one to one mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have two entities Person and Address. I have the following one to one relation:
1Person----->1 Address. The Person class has personId as primary key and addressId as foreign key. I need my foreign key addressId to be primary key in my Address entity. So far I have this in my mapping xml file:

```
<id name="addressId" type="int" column="ADDRESS_ID">
<generator class="foreign">
<param name="property">person</param>
</generator>
</id>
```

But doing this will take primary key from Person entity and set it as Primary key of Address entity. How can I set addressId from Person entity as primary key in Address entity? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, could you please try this and tell me if it works?

```
 <class name="Person">
        <id name="personId" column="personId">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="address" cascade="all"/>
    </class>

    <class name="Address">
        <id name="addressId" column="addressId">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">person</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="person" constrained="true"/>
    </class>
```

Comment: really, are you sure?